# S4B 2019 - Damaged Invitation [German Language]

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

in Office 2019 the S4B Outlook Plugin generates a damaged invitatioin in German language. 
[Damaged Invitation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhqW3.jpg)

In English it Looks Right 
[Right Invitation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LON1G.jpg)

Is there a way to reset the templates / take a look into the templates?
Where are they locatet?

Answer (score 0):

The invite is corrupt for some reason and outlook treats it as a message, not a meeting invite. Log into your account using web access - is the meeting invite showing up there as a meeting with accept/decline buttons?

For more information, please refer to these links:

[I can not accept or decline invites in outlook 2016](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/i-can-not-accept-or-decline-invites-in-outlook/a0264bb4-c41e-4176-b3a0-7eaf6e79662b)

You could use this method to customize meeting invitations:

[Customize meeting invitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/set-up-skype-for-business-online/customize-meeting-invitations)

Comment: Sorry, I should have named the real Problem not only in the title. It is only About S4B Meeting invitations. They appear corrupt by sending and receiving. In my opinion it's the S4B Outlook AddIn, which generate damaged invitations.


The Customizing takes no Effekt. In the corrupt inivtation an added logo does not appear. In the correct (english) Invitation the Customizing takes effect.